# Watir-Webdriver Window Switching Can't See Pop Up

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I have a website page that has a download button on it. When you click the download button some JavaScript is run which does:

```
document.location = "/reports/CSVReport.asp"
```

This results in a pop up (new window) that has a button to save and a button to cancel the download. This pop up is not the standard "where do you want to save the file" browser pop up. In Watir-Webdriver when I try:

```
puts browser.windows.size
```

it shows that it only sees 1 window.  I am currently using this with Firefox, and the window menu item of Firefox shows both windows and allows me to switch between them. Incidentally, the pop up window has no menu bar, I can't figure out how to inspect it with firebug, and I haven't found a way to view its source.  Any thoughts on why Watir-Webdriver can't see the window and how I might automate clicking the save button?

Comment: What OS is this happening on?  do you have any idea what csvreport.asp does?   Could you be looking at a javascript confirm box?

Comment: unless you provide a URL or some example code, no one will be able to help you here

Comment: I am currently running on OS X but hope to eventually run this on linux-headless. I apologize for not providing more source or a url. It is a "pay for service" site that I am currently accessing with a customer's login thus I can't hand out the url.

Comment: Is it ok to retract a question due to author foolishness? Setting the document.location as shown above was simply requesting a file from the server. The pop up box that I was seeing was a Firefox confirm download that was appearing (and was different than usual) because the file being requested had been tagged on the server with an invalid mime type. I apologize if I took up much of anyones time considering this issue.

Comment: @user1142012, No need to apologize or withdraw the question.  If this tricked you up, it could easily do the same to someone else.  Post an answer to your question and accept it.  Then the next poor soul who has a similar experience can learn from your pain instead of having to repeat it for themselves.